# Query recursiva SQLite

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, sqlite, recursão

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta a um banco de dados SQLite, possuo as seguintes tabelas:

Tabela sugestoes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sugestoes (
        id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        texto  VARCHAR(250),
        autor  VARCHAR(250),
        itens  VARCHAR(250),
        pontos INTEGER
    );
```

---

Tabela vertices

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vertices (
        id            INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        id_node_pai   INTEGER,
        id_node_filho INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (id_node_pai)   REFERENCES sugestoes(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_node_filho) REFERENCES sugestoes(id)
    );
```

---

Dentro delas eu possuo os seguintes dados:

[image: Imagem figurativa]

[image: Imagem figurativa]

---

Gostaria de obter a seguinte saída:

[image: Saída desejada]

---

Tenho feito a seguinte consulta:

```
WITH vertices AS (
    SELECT p.autor FROM sugestoes p, vertices e
        WHERE e.id_node_pai = p.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f.autor FROM sugestoes f
        INNER JOIN vertices d
        ON f.id = d.id_node_filho
)
    SELECT * FROM vertices;
```

Porém tenho obtido o seguinte erro:

```
Error: circular reference: vertices
```

Tentei usar o `WITH RECURSIVE`, porém sem sucesso também.

Comment: Precisa ser uma consulta recursiva? Você tentou com uma [*subquery* na cláusula SELECT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/subqueries.php), fazendo uma consulta na tabela `sugestoes.id` pelo campo `vertices.id_node_filho` dentro da consulta principal?

Comment: @Gomiero, confesso que não sei o que é uma subquery, eu pensei na recursividade justamente pois ela faz chamada a mesma tabela, porém sendo um node pai e um node filho, dei uma olhada em varias pessoas com problemas parecidos, porém nenhum resolveu este meu, se eu faço apenas a pesquisa por `UNION`, ele me retorna todos os valores que eu quero, porém em forma de uma única tabela, o que eu preciso é justamente a relação de pai e filho entre elas, vou fazer um teste com subquery para ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade diferente para solucionar o problema, é utilizar uma *subquery* dentro da cláusula SELECT, que procura o autor filho relacionado ao autor pai através da tabela `vertices` (selecionado na consulta principal).

A consulta fica da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT p.autor AS autor_pai,
       (SELECT q.autor
          FROM sugestoes AS q
         WHERE q.id = e.id_node_filho) AS autor_filho
  FROM vertices AS e, sugestoes AS p
 WHERE e.id_node_pai = p.id
```

Nessa consulta, para cada autor (pai) encontrado na tabela `vertices`, é feita uma nova consulta na tabela `sugestoes` pelo `id_node_filho`, retornando o campo `autor` (filho) que será exibido junto ao resultado da consulta principal.

Mais detalhes sobre subconsultas (em inglês): [SQLite: Subqueries](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/subqueries.php)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda e por me ensinar esse recurso, mas se puder, me tira outra duvida, esses `subqueries`, isso é um recurso da linguagem SQL ou apenas no SQLite?

Comment: De nada! É um recurso da linguagem SQL